# How can I add an HttpHeadAttribute wherever there's a HttpGetAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When writing API controller actions in ASP.NET Core 3.1+ I'd like to be able to put one attribute on a method and have it implement both the [HttpGet] and [HttpHead] behaviour simultaneously but with a different Name.

I would like something like this:

```cs
[HttpGetAndHead("{id}", Name = "GetChicken")]
public async Task<ActionResult<SuccessResponse>> GetChicken(int id) {}
```

That does exactly the same thing as

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetChicken")]
[HttpHead("{id}", Name = "GetChickenHeaders")]
public async Task<ActionResult<SuccessResponse>> GetChicken(int id) {}
```

**Is this possible? If so how can it be done?**

Currently I have this custom attribute that adds both GET and HEAD but sets the Name property the same for both and I'd like them separate. I'd like the HEAD operation to always be whatever the GET Name is + "Headers".

```cs
public class HttpGetAndHeadAttribute : HttpMethodAttribute
    {
    private static readonly IEnumerable<string> SupportedMethods = new[] { "GET", "HEAD" };

    public HttpGetAndHeadAttribute()
        : base(SupportedMethods)
    { }

    public HttpGetAndHeadAttribute(string template)
        : base(SupportedMethods, template)
    {
        if (template == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(template));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can apply multiple HTTP verbs using the `AcceptVerbs` attribute by using the OR operator.
Try the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
public async Task<ActionResult<SuccessResponse>> GetChicken(int id) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This answers part of the question but the bigger question is that the operationId set by the Name property isn't being set here and is thus identical for both.
Is there a way to also specify the Name property individually for each verb? Preferably it'd be done pragmatically...